# Equivalent Definitions of Projective Morphisms with Line Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is part b) of Vakil 17.3 A, self-study. We say a morphism $\pi: X \to Y$ is **projective** if $X$ is isomorphic as $Y$-schemes to the relative $\operatorname{Proj}$ of some quasicoherent sheaf of algebras $\mathcal L$ on $Y$ (such that $\mathcal L$ is finitely generated in degree $1$).

In part a) of this question, we are asked to show that $\pi$ is projective iff there is a finite type quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal L_1$ on $Y$ such that there exists a closed embedding of $Y$-schemes $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb P \mathcal L_1$. I believe I have done this.

Part b) takes it a step further: given an invertible sheaf $\mathcal L$ on $X$, we want to show $\pi$ is projective with $\mathcal O(1) \simeq \mathcal L$ iff there is a finite type quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal L_1$ on $Y$ such that there exists a closed embedding of $Y$-schemes $i: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb P \mathcal L_1$ with $i^* \mathcal O_{\mathbb P \mathcal L_1}(1) \simeq \mathcal L$.

I am only unable to show that given the latter, we get the isomorphism $\mathcal O(1) \simeq \mathcal L$ of the former. The only observation I have been able to make is that if we could show $i^* \mathcal O_{\mathbb P \mathcal L_1}(1) \simeq \mathcal O(1)$, we would be done. For example, we could show that $\mathcal L$ is very ample and that $X$ is a proper $Y$ scheme, which we have not shown, and, in fact, not even make precise outside the context in which $Y$ is an affine scheme, so I don't believe this is the intended route.